# Cannot read property 'panHandlers' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[I am practicing panResponder, but the error "can not read property  panResponder" of undefined always occurs. Can anyone help me?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElP9d.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvBrc.jpg)

Comment: render(){
        return(
              <View style={styles.container}>
                  <View
                      style={[styles.rect,{
                          marginLeft: this.state.left}]}
                      {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
                  />
              </View>
        );
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not add a comment.
Did you import PanResponder like this :

`var ReactNative = require('react-native');
var {
  PanResponder,
} = ReactNative;`

Or ES6:

`import { PanResponder } from 'react-native';`

Comment: oh my god, i wrote the code in componentDidMount...After changing to componentWIllMount, it did work

Comment: So how can we do in componentDidMount?

Answer (score 1):

I found that `{...this._panResponder.panHandlers}` was throwing error when panResponder functions were defined in componentDidMount() function.

It worked fine when componentWillMount() is used in place of componentDidMount().
But since componentWillMount() has been **deprecated**, I found that defining panHandler functions inside constructor solved the issue.

so try defining your functions like this

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            yourVariables: false
        };

        this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({ ..your logic here..});
}
```